# Is RSS source support HTTPS?

Tags: https, rss

I found the RSS feed source always is using `HTTP` protocol.

Is RSS feed support `HTTPS` protocol?

When I feed a RSS source, I may write the link: http://cn.engadget.com/rss.xml
or like: feed.appinn.com to the subscription software, like Feeds.

I have two questions:

1. If I write the `feed.appinn.com` to Feeds, is it will auto add the `http://` in the front of it?
2. Whether the RSS supports https protocol?

Comment: "Whether the RSS supports https protocol? " - It can.  Engadget's RSS service does not.

Comment: @Ramhound how about the first question? is it add the protocol automatically?

Comment: https:// cn.engadget.com/rss.xml works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not correct, RSS does not *support* anything underlying like HTTP, TCP, IP etc.

Nevertheless RSS feed as kind of data can be served either with HTTP or with HTTPS (or both) depending on the server settings.

Auto-addition: if you're use relative links in the header of a page then protocol of that page will be used. If you use absolute links then, well, you name the protocol.

Comment: whats meaning of your relative and absolute links?

Comment: Absolute: a href="http:// example.com/about.php". Relative: a href="/about.php"